# Manipulating returned eloquent collections

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was under the assumption that Eloquent returns collections, so the below would work;

```
$all_locations = Service::getLocationsForService($service_id, 'all');

$chosen_locations = Service::getLocationsForService($service_id, $locations);

$diff = $chosen_locations->diff($all_locations)
```

However I just get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::diff()`

Are these https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods only available at the point of making the query, and not manipulating an already returned collection?

Included the Query

```
public static function getLocationsForService($service_id, $locations)
    {
      if($locations[0] == 'all') { $locations[0] = ''; }
      return Service::with(['types', 'contacts', 'locations.datetimes' =>function($q) use($service_id){
        $q->where('service_id', $service_id);
      }, 'conditions', 'locations' => function($query) use($locations) {

        $ran = false;
        foreach($locations as $location)
        {
          if(!$ran)
          {
            $query->Where('town', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$location.'%');
          }
          else
          {
            $query->orWhere('town', 'like', '%'.$location.'%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$location.'%');
          }
          $ran = true;
          $query->Where('published', 1);
        }
      }])->find($service_id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain `get()` method to execute query and get a collection. Try this:

```
$all_locations = Service::getLocationsForService($service_id, 'all')->get();
```

Comment: The problem with that is the query ends with a find($id); chaining get pulls everything.

Do i just need to move the find to a where()?

Comment: @CraigWard please show all related code. `find()` would return an object, not a collection, but your code returns a Query Builder instance.

Comment: I've add the Query